# key not found in the db, return "None" or "not Found"?

Tags: database

I found this on an interview question.

> Should the data layer function: "get_person_by_key( person_key )"
>   return "None" or raise a "NotFound" exception if "person_key" does not
>   match a record in the database? Please explain your reasoning

Does this distinction make sense? I feel skeptical.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in general, as opposed to a specific issue. (interview question)

Comment: Maybe move to programmers?

Comment: The interview question is asking for your opinion of the proper solution (and asking you to explain why you formed that opinion). Your question here is also asking for opinion, and is therefore off-topic. (Opinion-based questions are inappropriate for SO's question/answer format, as there are no specific answers to the question being asked.) This is covered in the [help] topic regarding what types of questions should (and should not) be asked here.

Comment: I don't think that the company was very much interested in the one canonical right solution for this question. They simply wanted to see you reasoning. See how well you can explain your mind. See whether you care about the pros and cons of a possible solution. See your confidence and if you are able to stand your ground when another engineer tells you that your solution is bad. And so on …

Comment: Yes this is an opinion question. The idea is to pick which approach you feel is the best and then have good reasons to back your choice up.